# How to scan for odd digits in an integer, starting from the first?

Tags: c++, integer, digits

I need the user to input an integer with indefinite number of digits, and then I have to show all the odd digits in this integer starting from the first digit.

```cpp
long long num, a;
cin >> num;

while (num > 0)
{
    a = num % 10;
    num = num / 10;

    if (a % 2 != 0)
    {
        cout << a;
    }
}
```

This code shows all the odd digits but from the end of the integer.

Comment: Read a string, check it is a valid int, then walk the string from 0 if size is odd or from 1 if size is even and bigger than 1.

Comment: @rturrado I think they want to print if the value of the digit is odd, not its position.

Comment: @rturrado what does the size of the string have to do with anything? The OP wants to display all digits with an odd value, which means iterating through the whole string. The first digit could be odd, so it can't be skipped

Comment: Can you use `std::string`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau My mistake, sorry. I misread it as they wanted to output the digits with an odd index. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When a 'natural' sequence of events or operations leads you to get the correct results but in reverse order, then a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) is most likely the simplest tool to fix things.

Simply *push* each value onto the stack as you generate them; and then, when done, just run through that stack, and *pop* (and display) its contents until the stack is empty.

Here's a version of your code using the [`std::stack` container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

int main()
{
    long long num, a;
    std::cin >> num;
    std::stack<long long> digits;
    while (num > 0) {
        a = num % 10;
        if (a % 2) digits.push(a);
        num = num / 10;
    }
    while (!digits.empty()) {
        std::cout << digits.top();
        digits.pop();
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There will be more *efficient* code solutions, for sure, but the above is both easy to implement and clearly understandable.

---

Note that, as pointed out by [user4581301](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4581301/user4581301), the above code uses the `long long` data type, which has a limited size (that solution is based on the code you gave). However, if you truly want an arbitrary, *indefinite number of digits* (with no implied size limit), then you can read your input as a string and process that.

This also makes the solution *much* simpler, as the 'natural' analysis of that string will produce the results in the correct order, and you only need 'copy' the relevant (i.e. odd) digits from one string to another:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // (1) Read "arbitrary length" number as a string ...
    std::string number;
    std::cin >> number;
    // (2) Create a new string and append all odd digits to it ...
    std::string digodd{};
    for (auto c : number) {
        if (!isdigit(c)) {
            // Error handling for bad input ...
            std::cout << "Error: Non-digit found!";
            return -1;
        }
        auto digit = c - '0'; // Guaranteed to work by the Standard
        if (digit % 2) digodd += c;
    }
    // (3) Display the result string... 
    std::cout << digodd << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that this cannot handle an arbitrary length as it's capped by the maximum capacity of `long long`.

Comment: @user Fair comment. I was (carelessly, perhaps) basing my answer on the OP's code. Working ...

Comment: @user4581301 See edit. However, OP uses the word *indefinite* rather than *arbitrary*, so there is an element of doubt. However, using a string makes the whole process far simpler, anyway.

Comment: True enough. I interpreted indefinite as unknown and thus unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

I mean, technically, based on how the question is phrased, the answer is this. Works for an indeterminate number of digits - even more than available RAM:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        auto ch = (const char)_getch();
        if ( (ch == '1') || (ch == '3') || (ch == '5') || (ch == '7') || (ch == '9') )
        {
            std::cout << ch;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you add some way to break the loop, I like this answer.

Comment: Simple solution with one possible problem(OK Two problems): input of 123456j789 should probably be rejected with no output as it's not a number.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not considering negative numbers then it makes more sense to declare the variable `num` as having the unsigned integer type `unsigned long long int`.

A simple way to do the task is to write a recursive function.

Here is a demonstration program. As the user input I am using the maximum value of an object of the type unsigned long long int.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

std::ostream & output_odd_digits( unsigned long long int num, 
                                  std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    const unsigned long long int Base = 10;
    
    unsigned long long int digit = num % Base;
    
    if (  num / Base != 0 )
    {
        output_odd_digits( num / Base, os );
    }

    if ( digit % 2 != 0  ) os << digit;
    
    return os;
}

int main() 
{
    unsigned long long int num = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long int>::max();
    
    std::cout << num << '\n';
    
    output_odd_digits( num ) << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
18446744073709551615
17737955115
```

A non-recursive function can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

std::ostream & output_odd_digits( unsigned long long int num, 
                                  std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    const unsigned long long int Base = 10;
    
    unsigned long long int n = 1;
    
    for ( unsigned long long int tmp = num; tmp / Base != 0; tmp /= Base )
    {
        n *= Base;
    }
    
    for ( ; n != 0; n /= Base )
    {
        unsigned long long int digit = num / n;
        
        if ( digit % 2 != 0 ) os << digit;
        
        num %= n;
    }
    
    return os;
}

int main() 
{
    unsigned long long int num = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long int>::max();
    
    std::cout << num << '\n';
    
    output_odd_digits( num ) << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
18446744073709551615
17737955115
```

As you can see in the both cases there is no any need to use a standard container that occupies an additional memory.

Here is one more demonstration program where a separate function is not used.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const unsigned long long int Base = 10;

    while ( true )
    {
        unsigned int num;
        
        std::cout << "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): ";
        
        if ( !( std::cin >> num ) || ( num == 0 ) ) break;
        
        unsigned long long int n = 1;
    
        for ( unsigned long long int tmp = num; tmp / Base != 0; tmp /= Base )
        {
            n *= Base;
        }
    
        for ( ; n != 0; n /= Base )
        {
            unsigned long long int digit = num / n;
        
            if ( digit % 2 != 0 ) std::cout << digit;
        
            num %= n;
        }
        
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 1234567890
13579
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit ): 0
```